# In-memory adding of attribute to model XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Short question: is there a way to attach an attribute to the model XML tree in XSL, such that later on that attribute value can be retrieved/used?

Basically, I have a XML data-set, where I have a way of knowing that a "property" element is a leaf element, instead of having child "property" elements. For each leaf element, I call a template, by which a dot-notation full name is produced and stored as a variable. I'd like to attach that variable as an attribute to the XML data model for that element. This would allow me to do further processing, namely sorting on the attribute value. Is this possible.

For instance, if I have the following XML:

```
<property name="a">
    <property name="z" />
    <property name="w" />
    <property name="b">
       <property name="c" />
       <property name="b" />
    </property>
</property>
```

I want the following output:

```
a.b.b
a.b.c
a.w
a.z
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: **1.** Your input XML is invalid. **2.** Please post your XSLT and indicate XSLT version 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I edited the XML to correct the parsing issue. As far as the XSLT, I don't have something for the specific example - that's part of the question. Regarding version, XSLT version 1.0. This will have to work in a browser.

Comment: I thought you had "*a template, by which a dot-notation full name is produced and stored as a variable*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to produce the required output, using XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="leaves">
        <xsl:for-each select="//property[not(*)]">
            <property>
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </property>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- output -->
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($leaves)/property">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your corrected input:

```
<property name="a">
    <property name="z" />
    <property name="w" />
    <property name="b">
       <property name="c" />
       <property name="b" />
    </property>
</property>
```

the (text!) result is:

```
a.b.b
a.b.c
a.w
a.z
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate any input tree but it is possible to create temporary trees and to implement different manipulation steps in one transformation. With XSLT 2.0 that is easy, with 1.0 you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` on any tree fragments to process them further.